# Pass checked html attribute using Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, radio-button

I want to use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, htmlAttributes)` in ASP.NET MVC with one of the radio buttons checked by default, but it is not working. I've read a lot of posts about this in StackOverflow, but none of them has able to solve the issue. Any help on how to get this working is appreciated. Below is how my MVC looks like:

View

```
<h4>Search Book by:</h4>
<span>Title: </span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(expression: m => m.Input.SearchBy,value: "Title", htmlAttributes: new{@checked = true})
<span> | Isbn: </span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Input.SearchBy,"Isbn")
<span> | Author: </span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Input.SearchBy,"Author")
<span> | Publisher: </span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Input.SearchBy,"Publisher")

<button id="FindSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Find</button>
```

Model

```
public class GetBooksByConditionsParameters : AdminBookParametersBase
    {
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        public GetBooksByConditionsParameters() => OrderBy = "title";
        public uint MinPrice { get; set; }
        public uint MaxPrice { get; set; } = 10000;

        public bool ValidPriceRange => MinPrice < MaxPrice;      

        public class InputModel
        {
            public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }
            public string SearchBy = "Title";           
        }            
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Find()
{
    return View();           
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try ``new { Checked = "checked" }`` or ``new { @checked = "checked" }``

Comment: @Örvar I did multiple times, and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `@Html.RadioButton` to replace `@Html.RadioButtonFor`:

```
<span>Title: </span> @Html.RadioButton("Input.SearchBy", "Title", new { @checked = "checked" })
<span> | Isbn: </span> @Html.RadioButton("Input.SearchBy", "Isbn")
<span> | Author: </span> @Html.RadioButton("Input.SearchBy", "Author")
<span> | Publisher: </span> @Html.RadioButton("Input.SearchBy", "Publisher")
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it is working now. Thank you! But it is not binding the selected button to the SearchBy variable. What will be a good approach to get the string value into the SearchBy variable?

Comment: `But it is not binding the selected button to the SearchBy variable.` I test with form posting,when submitting the form,it will pass selected value of the radio buttons with name `Input.SearchBy`.Can you explain more about what you want?

Comment: With ```RadioButtonFor``` it automatically passes the string of selected radio button to variable ```SearchBy``` in my model. With ```RadioButton``` it passes the string var ```Input.SearchBy``` but it is not automatically copied to var in model. But I have it working now by using ```IFormCollection``` in controller to extract the value. Thank you very much for your help!